# simpleCart.js dynamic URL within Javascript

Tags: javascript, paypal, simplecart

I am wondering how I could pass a variable into the simpleCart function for different checkout links depending on which button is pressed.

**Buttons:**

```
$('.paypal_checkout').on('click', function(){
    window.checkoutlink = 'http://url.com/paypal';
     simpleCart.checkout();
               return true;
});

$('.stripe_checkout').on('click', function(){
    window.checkoutlink = 'http://url.com/stripe';
     simpleCart.checkout();
               return true;
});
```

**SimpleCart:**

```
    simpleCart({
        checkout: { 
            type: "SendForm" , 
            url: checkoutlink ,
        } 
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to edit the simpleCart.js file to make it work where it has SendForm I changed action = opts.url to the global variable checkoutlink which Is defined within my onclick function:

**edited simpleCart.js:**

```
                    action = checkoutlink,
                    method = opts.method === "GET" ? "GET" : "POST";
```

**buttons:**

```
$('.paypal_checkout').on('click', function(){
    window.checkoutlink = 'http://url.com/paypal';
     simpleCart.checkout();
               return true;
});

$('.stripe_checkout').on('click', function(){
    window.checkoutlink = 'http://url.com/stripe';
     simpleCart.checkout();
               return true;
});
```